# How can I move a few lines 10 or 15 columns to the right in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am using mvim and I use `10 <<` to move 10 lines to 2 columns left. However there are times when I want to move 10 lines to 7 columns left. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to select the lines visually, i.e., `V` then `9j`, and then type `7<`.

Answer (score 1):

This one starts on the following line `:.,+10<<7`.

See `:help <<`